# How to transform a byte array in string as per some custom encoding schema?

Tags: node.js, utf

A string "sजg" has 2 English keyboard characters and one Unicode character. It can be represented in byte array for different encoding schema as follows;

- UTF-8: [ 115, 224, 164, 156, 103 ]
- UTF-16: [ 115, 0, 28, 9, 103, 0 ]
- LB [( BigBit standard )](https://github.com/amitguptagwl/bigbit#linked-bytes-format): [ 115, 156, 18, 103]

I've written an encoder-decoder which can transform a number to a byte array and vice versa using Linked Bytes (LB) Format. How can I transform a string to byte array and vice versa?

In other words how any string encoder-decoder is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Though I've implemented it as a hack. But I'm still looking for the proper solution.

```
LBSequence.strToByteArr = function(str){
    const byteArr = [];
    for(let i=0; i< str.length; i++){
        let code = str.charCodeAt(i);
        byteArr.push(...LBSequence.encode(code));
    }
    return byteArr;
}

LBSequence.byteArrToStr = function(byteArr, start, end){
    start || (start = 0);
    end || (end  = byteArr.length);
    let str = '';
    while(start< end){
        let code = LBSequence.decode( byteArr, start );
        str += String.fromCharCode( code.val );
        start += code.len;
    }
    return str;
}
```